# How to cancel all pending $resource requests using promis on $state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngresource

I am trying to stop all the pending requests when a state change occurs.The below code works fine with $http but not with $resource.

```
                 var cancel=$q.defer();
    $http.get('api/cafservicestatus',{timeout:cancel.promise,cancel:cancel}).then(onsuccess,onerror);

    function onsuccess(result) {
        console.log(result)
    }

    function onerror(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }


    function stopHttp() {
        $http.pendingRequests.forEach(function(request) {
            if (request.cancel) {
                request.cancel.resolve();
            }
        });
    }
```

But this code doesn't work with $resource 
 Here is a sample code for $resource

```
             $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true,timeout:$q.defer().promise,cancel:$q.defer()},
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                }
                return data;
            }
        },
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
```

How can I stop all requests using $resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out this one.You must add a cancellable:true to your request and cancel the request in your controller using $cancelRequest()method of $resource.

for example, In your case

```
$resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
    'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true,cancellable:true},
    'get': {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                data = angular.fromJson(data);
            }
            return data;
        }
    },
    'update': { method:'PUT' }
});
```

and inside your controller

```
 var aborted= YourService.query();

//and later on state change

  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event){
     aborted.$cancelRequest();
      }
      );
```

Comment: This only solves problem for a particular controller.What I want is to cancel all requests at once and on $rootScope.But anyway, Thanks a lot